# How to use MAX function in SQL?

Tags: sql, max

This is my query:

```
SELECT Cottage15.CNUM,Cottage15.Rent,Assignment15.Hours
FROM Cottage15
INNER JOIN Assignment15
ON Cottage15.CNUM=Assignment15.CNUM
ORDER BY Assignment15.AID;
```

It works, but I can't figure out how to apply the `Max` function to `hours`? I was hoping that `MAX(Assignment15.Hours)` would work!?

This query shows all of the rows, but I only want it to show me certain rows that have the highest number based on the hour field.

Comment: You need to use `GROUP BY` along with it.

Comment: MAX is an aggregate function, you'll have to create groups to aggregate over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to get `max(hour)` per each `Cottage15.CNUM and Cottage15.Rent`
then use `max(Assignment15.Hours)` and `group by Cottage15.CNUM,Cottage15.Rent`:

```
SELECT Cottage15.CNUM,Cottage15.Rent,MAX(Assignment15.Hours)
FROM Cottage15
INNER JOIN Assignment15
ON Cottage15.CNUM=Assignment15.CNUM
GROUP BY Cottage15.CNUM,Cottage15.Rent
```

*But* if you want to get `Cottage15.CNUM and Cottage15.Rent` which have `max(Assignment15.Hours)` in the whole result set then you can get it by:

```
SELECT Cottage15.CNUM,Cottage15.Rent,Assignment15.Hours
FROM Cottage15
INNER JOIN Assignment15
ON Cottage15.CNUM=Assignment15.CNUM
WHERE Assignment15.Hours = ( SELECT MAX(Assignment15.Hours)
                             FROM Cottage15
                             INNER JOIN Assignment15
                             ON Cottage15.CNUM=Assignment15.CNUM
                            )
```

Comment: That seems to be bit more clear, but it didn't execute when I ran it :*(

Comment: why it didn't execute!!?? give a proper feedback, what do you mean by _didn't execute_ ? it gives error or didn't give expected output?

Comment: you just missed a semicolon at the end of query `;`

Comment: @rkail you are welcome, if it worked and was helpful you can accept it. by clicking on the check mark on the left side of answer

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want

```
SELECT Cottage15.CNUM,Cottage15.Rent,Assignment15.Hours
FROM Cottage15
INNER JOIN Assignment15
ON Cottage15.CNUM=Assignment15.CNUM
WHERE Assignment15.Hours = (SELECT MAX(Assignment15.Hours) FROM Assignment15)
ORDER BY Assignment15.Hours
```

Comment: It's still showing all of the data records (rows) when I ran this, I need it to only show the record with the highest number in hours field.

Comment: How about that? Sorry, it's hard to tell without any idea what your data means. If you could tell me what you wanted, it would really help me help you

Comment: That query didn't do anything. It didn't load any records When I run the query, it shows me all 15 records in the database. They are sorted. It looks great, however I only wana show records that have the number 5. 5 is the max value in my database, so I wanna show limited records. It's not doing that

Comment: I think what you need is to add a where clause

Answer (score 1):

you must add group aggregation to apply Max function

```
 SELECT Cottage15.CNUM,Cottage15.Rent,Max(Assignment15.Hours)
 FROM Cottage15
 INNER JOIN Assignment15
 ON Cottage15.CNUM=Assignment15.CNUM
 group by Cottage15.CNUM,Cottage15.Rent
 ORDER BY Assignment15.AID;
```